# Cyrillic characters display incorrectly (while retrieving data from Postgresql with psycorg2)

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, encoding, cyrillic

Spend a long time looking for similar problems to no awail.

So, I use Python 3.6 with psycorg2 to retrieve some data from a local database. While connecting, client_encoding='utf8' is specified.

The problem is that, instead of "рика", I get "аЁЄ\xa0". The result doesn't look like a clear example of any encoding, so .encode().decode() with different encodings got me nowhere so far.

What could be helpful:

— column the data is stored in has TEXT datatype (is it a bad choice for storing cyrillic characters?);

— database's Collate and CType is ru_RU.utf8, and "рика" is displayed correctly in psql;

— according to online decoders, "аЁЄ\xa0" is encoded in windows-1251, but it doesn't look like other strings in that encoding I've seen in other answers here.

Any ideas what's wrong there are appreciated.

UPD: TEXT datatype doesn't seem to be a problem; I tried storing 'рика' as a varchar and the return was the exact same mojibake.

Comment: Seems that 'рика'.encode('cp1125') == 'рика'.encode('cp866') == 'аЁЄ\xa0'.encode('cp1251') == b'\xe0\xa8\xaa\xa0' . Maybe you can check your encodings?

Comment: 'instead of "рика", I get "аЁЄ\xa0"' - _how_ do you get it, exactly?  Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @snakecharmerb `аЁЄ\xa0` is a a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `'рика'.encode('cp866').decode('cp1251')` returns `'аЁЄ\xa0'`…

Comment: Could it be the terminal encoding? @snakecharmerb

Comment: @JosefZ I'd guess so - it's likely that they see the issue when they print() the value - but they could have some weird PostgreSQL setup, or perhaps they see it in a webapp?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Hello! I do see this mojibake when I print the result of cursor.fetchall(). This is my first project so far, so could you specify what's considered a weird PostgreSQL setup? :) I use PostgreSQL 14 and access it through SQL Shell.

Comment: @Mivik database's encoding and psycorg2's client encoding are both UTF-8. I'll look into the encodings you mentioned, thanks!

Comment: I'd blame your terminal window. If I boot up Python REPL one way, saving `рика` to a variable and printing it back out gives me `????` and if I enter it from WSL using another, I'll get `рика`, and the difference between these is in the "current code page" (on Windows, r-click on the upper window bar, enter properties, it's in the first "Options" tab). The one that's working fine's in UTF-8, the other's not

Comment: @stardain I was wondering if there were any unusual encodings in your client config files, but it sounds like the issue may be printing in on Windows, in which case [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-can-i-use-unicode-characters-on-the-windows-command-line) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console) may help.

Comment: @Mivik Your suggestion helped me! For some reason combining two of those (.encode('cp1251').decode('CP866')) worked.

Comment: @JosefZ Hello! I came to the same solution with those two encodings, though reading into your answer more could've saved me an hour of my time. Thanks!

Comment: @Zegarek Didn't know I could do it, thanks!! Though after I changed it in my system and in IDE it still required some encoding fumbling. Maybe Linux just doesn't have that particular problem...

Comment: @snakecharmerb Not sure why, but this case seems to require a particular combination of encodings, even with codepage changed in the system and in IDE... Glad I researched it anyway, thanks for the resources!